# How to add repeated Footer to PDF Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, pdf, css

I have a requirement where I have to add a footer to PDF, This footer will be repeated for all the pages. I am generating this PDF using Visual force PDF renderAS functionality.

I have gone through various solutions in google and Salesforce knowledge articles too, but none of them worked for me.

Can anyone post me a sample code with repeated footer display for all the pages in PDF.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please refere to, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44944/display-header-and-footer-in-all-pdf-pages-using-vf

Comment: Any other solution without using components?

Answer (score 0):

It's all done in the CSS. Try something like this:

```
@page 
{
    @bottom‐left
    {
       content: element(footer);
    }
}
```

You'll also need to define the CSS for your footer too. Once you do, it will appear at the bottom-left of each page. Example of where to start:

```
div.footer
{
display: block;
padding: 5px;
position: running(footer);
}


<div class="footer">
<div align="center">
Otsuka Pharmaceutical Group.
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I used this but the problem is it is just disayi g the footer in the bottom it is not repeating and it just kind of normal text being displayed.

Comment: I thinks this can help you https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003705&language=en_US

Comment: @PraveenBiyani Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, particularly code you've written, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful. Had you told us what you'd tried and posted your code, I wouldn't have wasted my time posting something you'd already tried.

Comment: @crmprogdev I can't post every code here, I need client approval for the same. I can only explain the scenarios. Apologies for the inconvenience caused.