# How to make header and footer repeat on visualforce page rendered as PDF

Tags: visualforce, css, pdf, renderas

As I need to format a document that is going to be printed, and it is generated as PDF through the platform: How can I make the header and footer of the document repeat every page, regardless of the content?

And if the content is a table, how can I avoid breaking the row from one page to another?

Comment: You have two questions. For the first: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44944 ... For the second: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10500

Comment: Thanks. Now I don't know which one I refer to when I mark this one as a duplicate, though. Haha.

Comment: We can associate both questions as duplicates so long as we've completely helped you out.

Comment: Those two seem to cover what I want. Both can be marked as completed. If I need to, I can always create another question to be more specific.

Comment: All taken care of for you.